# How can I create a dashed border in CSS that would be symmetric horizontally/vertically?

Tags: css, frontend

I'm designing a website in Figma, and it allows me to create an evenly spaced border, that is symmetrical - corners are all identical, and dashes are now skewed or displaced relative to each other. I want to replicate similar behavior on my website, but I wasn't been able to find a solution that would work with adaptive UI -> the width and height of the div I want to put the border on isn't fixed.

I have attempted to use svg, and the dashed-border generator sites, but none do achieve the desired behavior. I expected it to be a common task, with a well-developed solution, but I wasn't able to google anything or use an AI for any working output. I have tried to export it from Figma, but none of the plugins work as well, even for static size.

[image]

Comment: `border-image` would be optimal I would suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with some background and gradients. Resize the below to see the result:

```css
.box {
  --c: red; 
  --t: 5px; /* border thickness */
 
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  
  
  border: var(--t) solid #0000;
  --b1:/calc(4*var(--t)) var(--t) linear-gradient(90deg,var(--c) 25%,#0000 0 75%,var(--c) 0) border-box round no-repeat;
  --b2:/var(--t) calc(4*var(--t)) linear-gradient(      var(--c) 25%,#0000 0 75%,var(--c) 0) border-box no-repeat round;
  background:
     0 0 var(--b1),0 100% var(--b1),
     0 0 var(--b2),100% 0 var(--b2);
     
  /* to debug */
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, CSS Wizard, it works! What exactly "no-repeat" and "round" do in these cases? So, for b1 you first round it horizontally, while it can still repeat, and then restrict it from repeating vertically. For b2, why do you have to change them places? 

I'm not sure exactly how those properties work with linear gradient and why do they produce the intended picture only in this order. Thanks in advance for your help and time!

Comment: @Luoencz b1 is used twice for the top and bottom while b2 is for the left and right. So i have to do the opposite logic. one should round on the X axis and not repeat on the Y axis and the other do the opposite on each axis that's what most of the values are simply permuted.